# Flutter - Get app version in iOS using package_info

Tags: dart, flutter, package-info

I need to retrieve the app version from within Dart code in a Flutter project.

I am using [package_info](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/package_info) and in Android is working OK but in iOS the version property in PackageInfo is null.

My code:

```
  Future<String> getVersion() async {
    String base = getText(version);
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    return base.replaceAll("[name]", packageInfo.version);
  }
```

Any help why is happening this or other way to retrieve the version? 
In some places of internet it is said that the version must be retrieved from native config files but in my case those files contains a reference to the version defined in pubspec.yaml.

I am using Flutter version 1.0.0

Thanks.

Comment: Could you check the CFBundleShortVersionString value in your ios/Runner/Info.plist file ?

Comment: @diegoveloper the value of CFBundleShortVersionString in info.plist is: $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)

Comment: Could you put a hardcode value and try again?

Comment: @diegoveloper I tried with a hardcoded value and it works, but that's precisely what I was trying to avoid, to have the same value in two different places...

Comment: Exactly @svprdga, im facing the same issue, its always returning 1.0.0, not the version i set in the pybspec.yaml, have u sorted that out ?

Comment: No @BishoyHanna, I just created another var with the version...so I have now the version in pubspec.yaml and in another place... :(

Comment: I do now change it in pubspec for android and in info plist for ios

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20761

Answer (score 0):

This package_info on iOS requires the Xcode build folder to be rebuilt after changes to the version string in pubspec.yaml. Clean the Xcode build folder with: XCode Menu -> Product -> (Holding Option Key) Clean build folder.
[see this](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/package_info#known-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Add below two line in your plist file inside dict:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Package Info Example</string>
```